# GOOGLE LOGIN IN IONIC APP

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

while making google login in ionic app getting error

```
scopes were invalid. {valid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly], invalid=[https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#email-scopes]}
```

Request Details

```
client_id=707870734492-q5dn4sc8vqf8o2231i1pm88ftrfi5jbd.apps.googleusercontent.com
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#email-scopes
immediate=false
hd=https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/reseller/v1/rest
include_granted_scopes=true
proxy=oauth2relay344347262
redirect_uri=postmessage
origin=http://localhost:8100
response_type=token
gsiwebsdk=1
state=252262168|0.4044143628
jsh=m;/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.SzB8Yr0eZhM.O/m=__features__/am=AQ/rt=j/d=1/rs=AGLTcCOTlQsaBke91_BUwWpWd1UeaxtVCA`
```

how we resolve this type of error,

Comment: post code where you define scopes

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer:

Change `https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#email-scopes` to `email`

---

#### Long answer:

Look for answer in your error:

> scopes were invalid.
>
> {valid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly],
>
> invalid=[https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#email-scopes]}

Instead to provide scope URL for `email`, you added URL to all auth email scopes, a.e.: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#email-scopes

This is a list of [all known scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes). Go ahead and define yours properly.

I would think about:

```
scope: [
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read', 
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',                
       'email'
        ],
```

---

As a side note check for [cordova google login plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)